# Приведение void* к указателю на метод

Tags: c++, указатели, dll

Возникли трудности в процессе написания динамической библиотеки, содержащей реализацию методов класса. Библиотека подключается к главному файлу в runtime через dlopen. Используя dlsym я получаю указатель, который указывает на метод класса. Однако dlsym возвращает void*, а его приведение к указателю на метод вызывает ошибку.

```
class Matrix{
    void inputMatrix();
};
const char* INPUT_MATRIX_FUNC_NAME = "_ZN6Matrix11inputMatrixEv";
typedef void (Matrix::*inputMatrixPtrT)();
void* hdl = dlopen(LIBRARY_NAME, RTLD_LAZY);
inputMatrixPtrT inputMatrix =(inputMatrixPtrT)dlsym(hdl,INPUT_MATRIX_FUNC_NAME);
```

> error: invalid cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘inputMatrixPtrT {aka
>   void (Matrix::*)()}’
>        inputMatrixPtrT inputMatrix = (inputMatrixPtrT)dlsym(hdl,INPUT_MATRIX_FUNC_NAME);

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Правильное решение — сделать метод статическим. Решение на свой страх и риск — reinterpret_cast<>. Объяснение в том, что указатель на метод (а вообще говоря и указатель на функцию) нельзя приводить к void* и обратно.

Comment: указател  на функцию-член - это не указатель. Мало того, размер указателя на функцию-член может быть больше, чем размер void*. Почему не использовать заголовочный файл библиотеки и не слинковать с библиотекой?

Comment: @Croessmah цель - научиться линковать в runtime

Comment: И можете почитать книжку "Сущность технологии COM". Автор, если не ошибаюсь, Дональд Бокс. В ней в самом начале показывается, как можно из библиотеки экспортировать классы (точнее, абстрактные классы).

Comment: @Fat-Zer а как тогда предлагаете динамически линковать библиотеки?

Comment: @Abyx, о каком api идет речь?

Comment: А в чем разница?